# Проверка авторизации пользователя

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Нужно что то на подобии `if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest)` (`Yii2`), только на `asp.net core`. Мне нужно узнать залогинился пользователь или нет.

Пробовал `System.Security.Claims.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, но он постоянно `false`
И так ошибка : `HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ:

```
 if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectToAction("Login", "Route");
```